# fprint-demo casusing authentication failure

Tags: password, authentication

I installed fprint-demo in Ubuntu 14.04 unfortunately I did not setup the finger prints and when I try to log in; its denying my password. I tried to remove the password in recovery mode:

rw -o remount /
passwd --delete *username*

reboot

But when the system reboots to log in without a password it says "failed to authenticate"